# Update query error on 1 field SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I keep getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show = '1'
>   WHERE ( owner  =  1  AND  id  =  63 )' at line 1

My query keeps crashing on column `show`, I can't figure out why.

This is how I am trying to update this column:

```
$show = (escape(Input::get('showcontact')) == '') ? 0 : 1;

$property->update(array(
                                'propertytype' => escape(Input::get('type')),
                                'address' => escape(Input::get('address')),
                                'postalcode' => escape(Input::get('postal')),
                                'sqf' => escape(Input::get('sqf')),
                                'price' => escape(Input::get('price')),
                                'deposit' => escape(Input::get('deposit')),
                                'description' => escape(Input::get('description')),
                                'listed' => escape(Input::get('list')),
                                'email' => escape(Input::get('email')),
                                'show' => $show,
                                'phone' => escape(Input::get('phone'))
                            ));
```

Column show is of type `smallint`. I can insert fine, I just can't update that column. If I comment out the `show`, my update query works fine.

I am really confused by this.

Comment: turn on query log so you can see your actual SQL.

Comment: This is error with `intval` SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show = '0', phone = '1 430 596 6696' WHERE ( owner  =  1  AND  id  =  63 )' at line 1  same thing I can't figure this out.. if I take out show form query it works fine!

Comment: `(escape(Input::get('showcontact'))) == '' ? 0 : 1;`

Comment: Is it possible that `show` is some kind of reserved keyword that is not allowed to be used in update?

Answer (score -1):

Ok I think I figured it out, I think column `show` is not allowed. I guess `show` is some sort of reserved keyword. I have changed the column to showw and it works fine the way it is.

Thanks for help guys

Added:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Yep SHOW is a keyword!

Comment: Who is the professional who voted down this? I created the question I found the solution and I have posted the answer. If you vote -1 at least explain your self, in my case changing the column name solved the problem and that is what I have stated.